# How to pronounce "magit"?

Tags: magit

**Q:** How does one pronounce *magit*?

It occurred to me today that I've never said "magit" out loud, and I'd prefer not to make a fool of myself if I ever have to do so.

So: is the *g* in *magit* pronounced as:

- a *j*, as in *magic*, or
- a hard *g*, as in *git*?

I suppose I've always said it as *j* in my head, but I could see the other way as well (aside from the unfortunate similarity to "maggot").

Comment: The creator of one of the early magit videos pronounced it with a j, as a play on "magic"

Comment: I don't think Alex Vollmer (video) is the same person as Marius Vollmer (original author).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Either "mu[m's] git" or ["magi{c => t}"](https://magit.vc/assets/videos/magic.mp4) is fine.

Comment: I _knew_ it wasn't maggot!

Comment: As the current maintainer, which of the two do you use?

Comment: My native language is a German dialect, so ... mu[m's] git" - which actually is the same as the German equivalent of  "magi{c => t}": "Mag{ie => it}".

Answer (score 1):

It should be pronounced [mæʤɪt] because it turns you into a magitian [məʤɪʃən].